# Moowoodle - Adding every user from shop

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, product

I have got a problem between my Woocommerce shop and the [Moowoodle for WooCommerce plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/moowoodle/) that acts as a bridge between WordPress/Woocommerce and Moodle. It fetches all the courses from your Moodle instance and makes them available for sale, which may be bought by users through WooCommerce.

The integration and everything works fine but the issue is following:

When somebody is buying the course the user is automatically added to the moodle userlist and can enroll to the course.(this feature works great)

Obviously when a customer is buying another product (not an online course ex. a book or sth) he get also linked to the Moodle userlist with a username + password for the Moodle via email.

I would like that **only the people who buy the actual course** will get the email with the access to the moodle.

What I am trying to do is something like:

> If user buys course_with_moodle_ID
>   then send email_with_login_info

You can find the source code [**here in Git**](https://github.com/dualcube/moowoodle).

Maybe someone could help me with a little fix because obviously the support to this plugin is very very slow and limited.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is another plugin that let you configure which product will generate a Moodle enrolment.
Disclaimer: I just wrote that plugin.
You can find it here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-to-moodle/

Comment: Great! I will check it out and leave you some feedback about it!